# export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-material2

I Installed Angular Material in my Angular Project. I had followed all the steps which were given in the [Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), but when I tried to run the application with 'npm start', I'm getting warnings and errors related to InjectionToken and Renderer2.

The error messages which I get in the console:

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js 138:33-47 "export 'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'
WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js 826:35-49 "export 'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'
WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js 1010:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js 1388:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js 3177:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/cdk/typings/bidi/directionality.d.ts (8,34): Module '"C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_mo dules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.
ERROR in C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/cdk/typings/table/cell.d.ts (8,22): Module '"C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
ERROR in C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/cdk/typings/table/row.d.ts (28,31): Type'IterableDiffer' is not generic.
ERROR in C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/cdk/typings/table/table.d.ts (8,69): Module '"C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
ERROR in C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/cdk/typings/table/table.d.ts (8,80): Module '"C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'TrackByFunction'.
ERROR in C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/scroll/scrollable.d.ts (8,49): Module '"C:/Users/naray/MEAN-project/client/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
```

Comment: whats the version of Angular you have installed. upgrage it to 4+ and then check.

Comment: `import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';` requires angular core 4.0+

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've upgraded to Angular 4 using 

"npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save"

Answer (score 1):

In my package.json I had both a reference to @ionic/angular and ionic-angular.

ionic-angular seems to be deprecated and replaced with @ionic/angular so when I installed ionic-angular, this resolved the error.

Comment: Bit confused. What did you perform? Did you remove ionic-angular?